# How to store fitdist objects in an array in R?

Tags: arrays, r

I want to store the results of `fitdist` in an array,

```
require(fitdistrplus)
fits = list()
fits[1] <- fitdist(data1,"norm")
fits[2] <- fitdist(data2,"norm")
```

but I receive the following warning message from R,

```
In fits[1] <- fitdist(data1,"norm") :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I don't know what the problem is in above code snippet.

Comment: Try `fits[[1]] <- ...`? (And if you know the number `n` of instances before-hand, it's might be better to pre-allocate with `fits <- replicate(n, NULL)`.)

Comment: In R, an array is a single vector with a dimensions attribute. You're talking about a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the warning message is that `fits[1]` is **unit length** thus can take only a single length object, and `fitdist(data1,"norm")` returns a list with **length greater than one**.

Your options are using

```
fits[[1]] <- list(fitdist(data1,"norm"))
```

as mentioned in a comment: the reason this works is that the class of `fits[[1]]` can be anything (while `fits[1]` is always a list of length 1).

So, if you have to use `fits[1]` format, you can use

```
 fits[1] <- list(fitdist(data1,"norm"))
```

which would make the output of `fitdist` a list of a list.